# Python Logging SMTP Handler message not sent

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi

I am using logging both to the rotating file handler and smtp handler -depending on level. Under Debian and Ubuntu - this logs using both handlers. I have same code running on a RaspberryPi. It logs to the rotating handler but I don't get the email. What additional config do I need for the rPi?

logging.conf

```
[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[loggers]
keys=root,simpleExample

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,rfileHandler

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s 
datefmt= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler,rfileHandler,email

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_rfileHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
backupCount=5
maxBytes=500
formatter=simpleFormatter
level=INFO
args=('/blabla/logs/blabla.log',)

[logger_simpleExample]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_email] 
class=handlers.SMTPHandler 
level=WARNING 
formatter=simpleFormatter 
args=('target url','sendemail',['erich@*****.com'],'EGIM Outstation Logger',  ('username','pw'))
```

Comment: Can you post your logging config?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by cloning separate logging configs for different processes.

Answer (score 0):

you must add `,` end of the tuple items that have a one item

```
args=('target url','sendemail',['erich@*****.com',],'EGIM Outstation Logger',  ('username','pw'))
```